# javascript object index keys

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure my javascript object. What I would like to have is an object where I can select nested objects via keys in a similar structure to this:

```
        trackObject:
            [{
            row1:{rowId:"#row1",rowSample:
                {sampleId:"#1",notes:
                    [0,400,800]
                }
            },
            row2:{rowId:"#row2",rowSample:
                {sampleId:"#2",notes:
                    [0,400,800]
                }
            },                
        }]
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to modify this object by indexing at the 'row' tier ie `row1` or `row2`. The problem is making the row name a variable. Ie the object above will return me the object I need by calling `trackObject.row1` but since the `row1` part needs to be dynamic i'm not sure how to index it from this point dynamically.

I've tried a few variations like not making `trackObject` an array but an object instead and changing row1 to `"row1":{rowId...` but then I havn't been able to reference the object property that it nests (`{rowId...`)

I've setup objects with keys in JSON before and it's been fine indexing by key but for some reason i'm struggling in js...

Comment: you might want to have a look at https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Answer (score 2):

You can access a member of an object by using bracket notation.

```
var obj = {
  row1: {
    rowId: '#row1'
  },
  row2: {
    rowId: '#row2'
  }
};

// index stored in variable
var index = 'row1';

// get row by using bracket notation
var row = obj[index];

console.log(row.rowId); // '#row1';
```

Comment: it is more [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), than *array notation*-

Comment: Sorry it was probably worth mentioning that i'm using React and this object lives in the getInitialState part of a component. I don't think i'm allowed to create variables as you have done in your answer above in the getInitialState... at least trying it with your syntax is spitting out errors..

Comment: WHat would equally solve my issue is if I could navigate to the next key in the object. IE find object where rowId = "row1" and from there find its sibling rowSample

Answer (score 0):

The convenient way *to structure your javascript object.*
Consider using custom *getter* method which accepts ***row*** index/number as a parameter:

```js
var data = {
  trackObject :
  {
    row1: {
      rowId: "#row1",
      rowSample: {
        sampleId: "#1",
        notes: [0,400,800]
      }
    },
    row2: {
      rowId: "#row2",
      rowSample: {
        sampleId: "#2",
        notes: [0,400,800]
      }
    },                
  },
  getRow : function (idx) {
    var obj = this.trackObject['row' + idx];
    if (!obj) {
      throw new Error("Undefined trackObject key: row" + idx);
    }
    return obj;
  }
};

console.log(data.getRow(2).rowSample);
console.log(data.getRow(5).rowSample); // will throw "Uncaught Error: Undefined trackObject key: row5"
```